# Absolute convergence of series $f_n(x)+g_n(x)$ implies convergence of series $f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

Consider two function series $\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x)$. The following implication holds:

> $$\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \text{ converges absolutely and } \sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x) \text{ converges absolutely} \\ \implies \sum_{n\geq 0} (f_n(x)+g_n(x)) \text{ converges absolutely}$$

But also the following proposition is true in general for another  function series $\sum_{n\geq 0} h_n(x)$

> If $\sum_{n\geq 0} h_n(x)$ converges absolutely, then also every
>   subseries converges.

So in particular if $h_n(x)=f_n(x)+g_n(x)$, can I say the following?

> $$\sum_{n\geq 0} (f_n(x)+g_n(x)) \text{ converges absolutely} \\
> \implies\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \text{ converges and } \sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x) \text{ converges}  $$

If this is true, then is the convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x)$ conditional, in general or is it absolute?

Comment: This is wrong, take $f_n(x)=n=-g_n(x)$.

Comment: Notice the proper use of \text{} in MathJax, as in my edit to this question. $\qquad$

Comment: A subseries of the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ is a series of the form $\sum\limits_nx_{\varphi(n)}$ where $\varphi:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is increasing, hence $\sum\limits_nx_n$ is not a *subseries* of $\sum\limits_n(x_n+y_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $1/n^2$. As one sequence, and split it in to $1/n$ and $1/n^2 - 1/n$. And these are not subseries.